# How do i generate release notes based on revisions in AnkhSVN?

Tags: ankhsvn

I'm using AnkhSVN in Visual Studio 2010.
How do i generate release notes based on revisions in AnkhSVN?
Is there any way to import Revision's message to Notepad and all?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve this one? I would like to include the SVN revision number in a configuration page in a C# / ASP.NET project with razor and ankhsvn, but I don't know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tortoise SVN.

In Tortoise SVN, there is a log system. these logs contains information about file you committed. So you can copy this log and then make some formatting to look better.